# MySQL jdbc connection takes too long

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to connect to the mysql server, but this takes 5 seconds.

```
showTime();
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.212:3306/db",username.getText(),password.getText());
showTime();
```

Comment: share minimal and complete testable code.

Comment: Your connection may be slow or the server might be heavily loaded

Comment: with almost empty database  ~100 rows it is relatively quick. With 700+ rows it takes 5 seconds or more only to connect.

Comment: Can you show us some code of what you are trying to do here so that we can figure out what's taking too long ? maybe it's not in the connection setup

Comment: I'm just creating the layout for a JFrame, nothing else.The code above is in an Action Listener. Between the two showTime() is a 5 second pause.

Comment: What do you mean with "700+ rows"? Your code does not retrieve anything from the database, so it's completely irrelevant how many rows the "database" contains.

Comment: I thought that there should not be any difference since I am not executing any query, but when the database was smaller I did not have to wait 5 seconds for the connection to establish. It's strange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was actually with the mysql server. I was running Windows Server 2008R2, and after I exhausted all possible answers I decided to uninstall windows and install Ubuntu Server. After that, the same exact snippet of code worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [`Connection Pool`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool) where connections are already created and stored in the pool instead of creating at run-time.

> In software engineering, a connection pool is a cache of database connections maintained so that the connections can be reused when future requests to the database are required.
>
> Connection pools are used to enhance the `performance` of executing commands on a database.

I have already shared a nice [ConnectionUtil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22999830/servlet-server-side-initialization-code-in-gwt/23006184#23006184) class to manage all the connections in a single class for whole application.

Use `JNDI` to bind the [data-source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datasource) with the application rather than hard-coding username/password and configuration in the java class itself.

It's better explained under *Java Tutorial* on [Connecting with DataSource Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqldatasources.html)

> `DataSource` objects can provide connection pooling and distributed transactions. This functionality is essential for enterprise database computing.

There is one more post on StackOverflow [Why do we use a DataSource instead of a DriverManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15198319/why-do-we-use-a-datasource-instead-of-a-drivermanager) that explain it as well.

---

Move the driver class loading step in the [Static Initialization Block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095344/calling-non-static-method-from-static-member-in-java/24095354#24095354)

```
static{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
}
```

Comment: I'm doing this at the log-in point. Throughout the classes I pass this Connection and it works fine.

Comment: don't you think that data-source must be loaded before application start to server the request.

Comment: I just changed that, still 5 seconds :(

Comment: I just tried it, unfortunately I have the same result

Comment: I just tried it with DataSource and it still takes 5 seconds to establish a connection

Answer (score 0):

Braj is right about connection pooling but in case your application is not executed in a heavy container and in case is just a tiny database access, I advise you to test your connexion with a mysql client  to figure out  which part is slow (your application or the DBMS itself).

Comment: The database is relatively small. The connection works perfect with phpmyadmin. It only takes long to establish the Connection.